# How To Monitor Available Disk Space

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation

We have constant problems with the available space and no financial means to upgrade it. Therefore I have to be very careful in my monitoring of the database size, its growth and the remaining free space. Every morning, I'm manually running the query to get the free space and I'm copying results to an excel file. As you can imagine it is rather daunting process and its wastes plenty of my time because I have to do it for every server separately.

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically retrieve the statistics (especially free space left) from the production environment and move it to a special table in the same or another database/server. I would like for the table to be automatically updated daily. It doesn't have to be a table. Any way that lets me save my time on daily basis will be appreciated.

Could you advise? Do you have similar solutions in your databases? Please share your experiences.

!

Comment: You should look into Integration Services.

Comment: Which particular function of ssis do you have in mind?

Comment: You can setup a package with a Sql command task with your queries and a Email Task to send you a email with the results. Schedule it on the Sql Server Agent to run daily. You can achieve this in many ways within SSIS.

Comment: Check out stored proc `xp_fixeddrives` (Note: it is undocumented and not supported, IIRC.)  There are lots of possibilities here.  You could set up a SQL Agent job to run periodically, capture the amount of free space left in each job, save it to a table, email a report, etc

Comment: Thank @mxix I'll look into your suggestion. To be honest I never thought of using SSIS for this particular purpose. Now that you pointed it out it seems obvious. I'll try.

Comment: Thank you @DMason xp_fixeddrives seems to be simpler than the query, which I'm using now. Following your suggestion I'll try to set up a new job in SQL Server agent.

Comment: `xp_fixeddrives` is undocumented, not supported, and may stop working at any time. [`sys.dm_os_volume_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223223.aspx) is much easier to use, is documented and supported, and actually has useful information that the XP lacks : drive size. The XP tells you there are 30 MB free, but is that 30 MB of 300 MB, or 30 MB of 300 TB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an SP to get things started.  I will assume that you have already set up Database Mail and it is functioning properly.  You can run it manually to see how it works.  Adjust the default value of @FreeSpaceThresholdMB as needed.  The SP has some limitations:

- It can only check free space available
- It won't check space used
- It won't show based on a percentage

.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckFixedDriveFreeSpace
@FreeSpaceThresholdMB INT = 1024
AS
--Name     : dbo.CheckFixedDriveFreeSpace
--Purpose  : Performs a rudimentary check of free space on fixed drives,
--           sends an email as needed.
--Inputs   : @FreeSpaceThresholdMB - the threshold for checking free disk space.
--              If free space is greater, no action is taken.  If less, an
--              email is sent.
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #FixedDrives (
        Drive CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
        MBFree INT
    )

    INSERT INTO #FixedDrives EXEC xp_fixeddrives

    DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrMsg = ''

    SELECT @ErrMsg = @ErrMsg + fd.Drive + ':' + CHAR(9) + CAST(fd.MBFree AS VARCHAR) + ' MB' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM #FixedDrives fd
    WHERE fd.MBFree < @FreeSpaceThresholdMB

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrMsg = 'Warning: one or more disk drives is running out of free space:' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @ErrMsg
        DECLARE @Subj NVARCHAR(255) 
        SET @Subj = @@SERVERNAME + ' - Low Disk Space'
        EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients = 'Your email address', 
            @Subject = @Subj,
            @body = @ErrMsg
    END

    DROP TABLE #FixedDrives
END
GO
```

You can "hook up" the SP to a SQL Agent Job, and schedule it to run as often as you like.  Here is an "hourly" schedule:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules s
    WHERE s.name = N'DBA-Hourly Schedule'
)
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule 
        @schedule_name=N'DBA-Hourly Schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=8, 
        @freq_subday_interval=1,  
        @active_start_date=20140101, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959
GO
```

Next, create a SQL Agent Job:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space')
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job 
        @job_name=N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Self-explanatory.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'Some Operator',
        @notify_page_operator_name=N'Some Operator',
        @start_step_id = 1

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule
        @job_name=N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space',
        @schedule_name=N'DBA-Hourly Schedule'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver 
        @job_name=N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space', 
        @server_name = N'(local)'
END
GO
```

Add the job step(s):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space')
BEGIN
    --Calling sp_delete_jobstep with a step_id value of zero deletes all job steps for the job.
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep
        @job_name=N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space', 
        @step_id=0

    DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Cmd = N'EXEC dbo.CheckFixedDriveFreeSpace
    @FreeSpaceThresholdMB = 1024    --Or Whatever number you want
GO'
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep 
        @job_name=N'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space', 
        @step_name=N'Check Fixed Drive Free Space', 
        --@step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, 
        @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=@Cmd, 
        --Name Of The DB Where You Created [dbo].[CheckFixedDriveFreeSpace]
        @database_name=N'ReplaceMe', 
        @flags=0
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR('SQL Server job "DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space" does not exist.', 16, 1);
GO
```

Now let's take a moment to think about what we've created...
We've got a SQL Agent Job running once per hour at the "top of the hour".  It executes the SP that sends email when available disk space is low.  That's a good start, but it has some shortcomings.  The big drawback is that our job is only triggered by the schedule.  If there are events that rapidly consume disk space, one or more disks may run out of space well before the job is run--we won't know until it's too late.  If you want to pursue this further, we can enhance what has been created so far with event notifications.  NOTE: I believe you will need SQL Server 2008 or later.

There are events for DATA_FILE_AUTO_GROW and LOG_FILE_AUTO_GROW.  Let's "hook into" those events, so that every time a data or log file grows, we automatically check our disks.

```
--Create a queue just for file autogrowth events.
CREATE QUEUE queFileAutoGrowthNotification
GO

--Create a service just for file autogrowth events.
CREATE SERVICE svcFileAutoGrowthNotification
ON QUEUE queFileAutoGrowthNotification ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification])
GO

-- Create the event notification for file autogrowth events on the service.
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION enFileAutoGrowthEvents
ON SERVER
WITH FAN_IN
FOR DATA_FILE_AUTO_GROW, LOG_FILE_AUTO_GROW
TO SERVICE 'svcFileAutoGrowthNotification', 'current database';
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReceiveFileAutoGrowthEvent
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @MsgBody XML

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Receive the next available message FROM the queue
        WAITFOR (
            RECEIVE TOP(1) -- just handle one message at a time
                @MsgBody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
                FROM queFileAutoGrowthNotification
        ), TIMEOUT 1000  -- if the queue is empty for one second, give UPDATE and go away
        -- If we didn't get anything, bail out
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            BREAK
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --Although we've captured the message body, we're not using any of the event data.

            --Run this SP when the event is triggered.
            EXEC [ReplaceMe].dbo.CheckFixedDriveFreeSpace
                @FreeSpaceThresholdMB = 1024    --Or Whatever number you want.

            /*
                Alternatively, you could start a SQL Agent job when the event is triggered.
                (You won't be able to do this with SQLExpress versions.)

                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 
                    @job_name = 'DBA-Check Fixed Drive Free Space'
            */

            /*
                Commit the transaction.  At any point before this, we 
                could roll back -- the received message would be back 
                on the queue AND the response wouldn't be sent.
            */
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
    END
END
GO

ALTER QUEUE dbo.queFileAutoGrowthNotification 
WITH 
STATUS = ON, 
ACTIVATION ( 
    PROCEDURE_NAME = dbo.ReceiveFileAutoGrowthEvent, 
    STATUS = ON, 
    --STATUS = OFF, 
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER) 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered SQL Server Agent Job? In Microsoft SQL Management Studio, expand the SQL Server agent node in the Object explorer, rightclick on the Jobs node and select New Job...

Comment: I'll look into it. What should the steps within the job be. How do you think?

Comment: @QWE look here to get started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using powershell script to do the job. Please read this [topic](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1759/retrieve-a-list-of-sql-server-databases-and-their-properties-using-powershell/) it talks about what you want.